# Add_rewrite_endpoint doesn't work with post name permalink structure

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I am adding a "Conversations" endpoint so that it appears in my account in woocommerce

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'custom_endpoints') );
function custom_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'conversations', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
}
```

It will work just fine with a "plain" permalink structure, but with a post name structure the link in my account goes to `my-account/conversations.`That says "page not found". However `my-account/?conversations` does work.

What's causing this?

This is the code for the WooCommerce menu items:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array($this, 'custom_items'), 10, 1 );
    function custom_items( $items ) {

            $items = array_slice($items, 0, 2, true) +
                array("conversations" => esc_html__( 'Conversations', 'domain' )) + 
                array_slice($items, 2, count($items)-2, true);

        return $items;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `add_rewrite_endpoint()` directly to register account page endpoints in WooCommerce. WooCommerce has a filter that you can use that make sure everything else works properly, like the endpoint title filter and calls to `is_wc_endpoint_url()`.

So add the endpoint with the `woocommerce_get_query_vars` filter:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_get_query_vars',
    function( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars['conversations'] = 'conversations';

        return $query_vars;
    }
);
```

Note that unlike the `query_vars` filter, you need to use a key when adding to the array.

Now you can set the page contents with the `woocommerce_account_conversations_endpoint` hook:

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_account_conversations_endpoint',
    function() {
        // Page content here.
    }
);
```

And the title with the `woocommerce_endpoint_conversations_title` filter:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_endpoint_conversations_title',
    function( $title ) {
        $title = 'Conversations';

        return $title;
    }
);
```

And you can continue adding it to the account menu the way you are.

Comment: Jacob, thanks so much for your response. 

I'm still having the same issue unfortunately. Wc_get_account_endpoint_url('conversations') shows me `http://localhost:10018/my-account/conversations/` but that goes to 404-> not found. `http://localhost:10018/my-account/?conversations` is the only one that works.

I tried flushing rewrite rules. Also tried Incognito mode. Maybe It's because I'm using Local by Flywheel and it's somehow interfering. I'll try on a live website

Comment: It's possible there's a plugin interfering. Try with other plugins disabled and a default theme.

Comment: No other plugin and using the default theme. It works in the Live Website! Doesn't work in the local environment. I guess it must have something to do with the way Local handles the domain. No idea... oh well...thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Even if I was saving permalinks, that wasn't actually flushing the rewrite rules.

I was flushing rewrite rules on activation but I was doing it incorrectly.

If you are adding custom endpoints, you need to call the function that adds the custom endpoint in the activation file, before the flush_rewrite_rules() call.

This is in my activation function now and it works:

```
require_once ( PLUGIN_DIR . 'public/class-plugin-public.php' );

        $publicobj = new Plugin_Public;
        $publicobj->custom_endpoints();

        // Flush rewrite rules
        flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Now I'm instantiating the public class and calling the endpoints() method in the activation, before the rules flush.